# Picasso error loading image from the phone

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-gridview, picasso

I have a GridView in which I put some Images picked from the phone using Picasso (I'm targeting only KitKat at the moment). I'm passing an ArrayList of Uri to the Adapter and all works fine. But I want that the images stay here also after the activity is destroyed so I'm using inside my Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    imagesUriSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for(Uri i : imagesUri)
        imagesUriSet.add(i.toString());
    mSharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("IMAGES",imagesUriSet).commit();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Where imagesUri is the ArrayList with the Uri of the images I want to be in the GridViwe. Using onPause may not be the best choice but it's not important for me at the moment.

On the onCreateView of my Fragment

```
    Set<String> set = mSharedPreferences.getStringSet("IMAGES", null);

    if(set != null)
        for(String uriString : set) {
            imagesUri.add(Uri.parse(uriString));
            Log.i("Immagine: ", Uri.parse(uriString) + "");
        }

    gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The Adapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                           ArrayList data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new SquaredImageView(context);
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }

        Uri url = (Uri) data.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context) //
                .load(url) //
                .fit() //
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(view);

        return view;
    }
}
```

If I launch my app, the images that I saved in my SharedPreferences aren't displayed, and I see the error image instead. But if I add the same image again, then I can see also the first one.
I'm not sure what's happening. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and do a Log.I and see what is being both written to and read from SharedPreferences to see if it actually writes/reads the correct values?
And also try to do Log.I and see if the correct URL is being read when you're doing "Uri url = (Uri) data.get(position);" in the getView() method.

My best guess is somewhere along the way, it fails to set/get the correct data from SharedPreferences.

I'm currently also using Picasso to load a lot of pictures (Facebook/Twitter/LinkedIn profile pictures) in a ListView, though i'm not saving the URL addresses in SharedPreferences, i'm saving them in a database (along with other information).
I haven't had any issues with it at all.

Comment: But why when I add the same Image again can I  see both? I tried to use Log and everything is correct ....